# 2D lattice, primitive cell choice

Tags: solid-state-physics, lattice-model

I have a question regarding the choice of a primitive cell in this 2D lattice:
[image]

In my book (Ashcroft) it says: The obvious primitive cell to associate with a particular set of primitive vectors, **$a_1$**,**$a_2$**,**$a_3$** , is the set of all points **r** of the form: $\textbf r= x_1 \textbf a_1+x_2\textbf a_2+x_3\textbf a_3$, $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are in the range of 0 to 1. So I made the choice to describe the lattice with two primitve vectors and a 2 point basis, that means that the primitve cell should be (a1 and a2 are primitve vectors) :

[image]

but apparently  this is wrong and this is the right choice: 
[image]

Can someone please explain what's wrong with my choice of a primitive cell, because it gives the wrong results later on when calculating the fourier coefficients of the lattice potential...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primitive cell is perfectly fine. You just need to be careful that the vectors pointing to the atoms in the unit cell are now different for your choice than for the one made in the book.

The mistake must be somewhere else. Keep in mind that depending on where in the crystal you put your origin, the Fourier coefficients might get a phase factor.

Comment: If the potential consist of delta functions is this correct: 
$U_\textbf k=\frac{V_0}{S}\int_{primitve\space cell} \textbf[\delta(r)+\delta(r- a1)+\delta(r-a1-\frac{1}{2}\space a2)+\delta(r-a1-a2)+\delta(r-\frac{1}{2} a1-a2)+\delta(r-a2)+\delta(r-\frac{1}{2} a2)\textbf] e^{-i \textbf K r} \space dr\space =\frac{V_0}{S }(4+2(-1)^m+2(-1)^n)$

Comment: For the fourier coefficient of the potenital corresponding to the K-th vector of the reciprocal space ? I am killing myself with this, somehow I don't get the right solution...

Comment: Where :  $K=\frac{2\pi}{a}(m,n)$

Comment: If I counted correctly you have 7 delta distributions in your formula. I count 8 atoms. But these atoms are not counted equally. so that I miss prefactors to your deltas. Atoms at a corner count 1/4, atoms on an edge count 1/2. Overall this should only add up to 3 whole atoms.

Comment: You are indeed missing the atom at $a_1/2$

Comment: $U_\textbf k=\frac{V_0}{S}\int_{primitve\space cell} \text[\delta(r)+\delta(r-\frac{1}{2}a1)+\delta(r- a1)+\delta(r-a1-\frac{1}{2}\space a2)+\delta(r-a1-a2)+\delta(r-\frac{1}{2} a1-a2)+\delta(r-a2)+\delta(r-\frac{1}{2} a2)] $

Comment: @GregorMichalicek Thank you very much!! I didn't know that deltas can be "cut up" like that! This realy saved me ! Thank you both !